# Python, Tkinter: How to get the handle of all canvas objects using their IDs or tags?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like get the handles of all rectangles on a canvas with a certain tag to place them with the grid geometry manager (the user can move them around by mouse-dragging and then I would like to "reorder" them for him). I do not have the handles of the rectangles, but they all have the same tag ("moveable_canvas"). From there I can convert to the item id (.find_withtag) but what now? The the ID I could to an .itemconfigure etc., but how to "grid" them?

```
moveable_canvases = self.canv.find_withtag("moveable_canvas")
for canvas_id in moveable_canvases:
    ???.grid(...)
```

Comment: Why not just place those rectangle references in a `list`?

Comment: Because they are generated by different subclasses dynamically as the user interacts with the program. I found it easier to search for them using the tag just in time when I need them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Find the object ids

You can use the various find* methods of the canvas to find all of the objects. For example, to get a list of all object ids you would do something like this:

```
self.canv.find_all()
```

To find all with with a given tag you would use `find_withtag` rather than `find_all`:

```
self.canv.find_withtag("moveable_canvas")
```

### Arrange them in a grid

You said that the goal was to get these object ids so that you can use `grid`. You cannot do that. `grid` only works on widgets, not canvas objects. There is no workaround. There is no way to convert one to the other.

If you want to arrange the items in a grid then you will have to do the math yourself, and use the `coords` or `move` canvas methods to align the objects.

Comment: Ok. I see. As you said 'grid' only works on widgets, not canvas objects. I will use 'move' to move them around with manual math.